# Analyzing read operation using Procmon

Tags: c++, file-io, procmon

I am trying to analyze a basic read operation using ifstream with Procmon.

Part of the code used for read operation where i was trying to read data of 16kb size from a file:

```
char * buffer = new char[128000];
ifstream fileHandle("file.txt");
fileHandle.read(buffer, 16000);
cout << buffer << endl;
fileHandle.close();
```

In Procmon there were 4 ReadFile operation with the following details:

Offset: 0, Length: 4,096, Priority: Normal
Offset: 4,096, Length: 4,096
Offset: 8,192, Length: 4,096
Offset: 12,288, Length: 4,096

So does it mean that there were 4 operations of each 4kb size ? and if so why did that happen instead of just having a single ReadFile operation of 16 kb size.

Answer (score 2):

> So does it mean that there were 4 operations of each 4kb size ?

Yes.

> and if so why did that happen instead of just having a single ReadFile operation of 16 kb size.

Probably because the standard library shipped with your compiler sets the default size of the buffer of file streams to 4 KB; since the `read` operation has to go through the buffer, it has to be filled (through OS calls) and emptied 4 times before satisfying your request. Notice that you can change the internal buffer of an `fstream` using [`fileHandle.rdbuf->pubsetbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubsetbuf/).

Comment: I will experiment more by changing the internal buffer and see how that works.

Comment: For 16 KB I doubt you'll manage to see any significant difference... the initial IO cost is going to hide completely the cost of two extra syscalls, and if you are going for performance `fstream` is a dead end anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to read 16 Kb in a single operation using  fileHandle.rdbuf.

Answer (score 1):

> So does it mean that there were 4 operations of each 4kb size ?

That is exactly what it is saying.

> and if so why did that happen instead of just having a single ReadFile operation of 16 kb size.

Just because *you* asked for 16000 bytes does not mean `ifstream` can actually read 16000 bytes in a single operation.  File systems do not usually allow for such large reads, there is usually a cap.  Even if you increase the size of the internal buffer that `ifstream` uses internaly, that is still no guarantee that the file system will honor a larger read size.

The contract of `read()` is that it returns the requested number of bytes unless an EOF/error is encountered.  HOW it accomplishes that reading internally is an implementation detail.  In this case, `ifstream` had to read four 4KB blocks in order to return 16000 bytes.

Comment: I don't think that, at this level, the filesystem implementation matters in any other way than suggesting the designers of the CRT to use 4096 as default block size. `ReadFile` per se is quite a high-level API, you can ask to it any size (and pass any kind of file handle) and it will happily oblige, blocking until it fetches all the requested data; the filesystem drivers limitations are way below it.